# Excel matching data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have excel that have columns like "Username" and "Serial"

On the other sheet I have only column "Serial", how can I retrieve data from Sheet1 that have name and serial to my other Sheet2, that only have "Serial". So I can match the serials and users.

Sheet2 data comes from our PC supplier and Sheet1 data is report from our PC inventory

Below is screenshot from what I want accomplish

[image]

Comment: What does the data look like? Sounds like you may be able to use `VLOOKUP()`.  What have you tried?

Comment: This is a classic lookup problem.  VLOOKUP requires the search column to be the leftmost.  Look at INDEX plus MATCH.

Comment: I got this to work with VLOOKUP after I rearrange data correctly so that serial column is leftmost. So thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve the issue you need Reverse Lookup.**

[image]

Write this array formula is Cell `H2` of `Sheet 2`,  finish the formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2,CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet1!B2:B6,Sheet1!A2:A6),2,0),"")}
```

**Or,**

*you can use this `Index & Match` combination also in Cell `H2` of `Sheet 2`.*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A10,MATCH(G2,Sheet1!B2:B10,0),1),"")
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*